# Is it possible to tap a hole partially through a 3mm aluminium sheet?

Tags: machining, aluminum, fasteners, threads, cutting

I would like to secure components to an aluminium sheet that is 3mm thick. Ideally I do not want to drill holes all the way through the sheet because it is important that a seal is maintained.

I am therefore wondering whether it might be realistic to fasten my components to the aluminium sheet using partially tapped holes in it. For example, a 3mm diameter tapped hole that goes to a depth of 2mm in the aluminium sheet.

To me, these dimensions seem pretty tight. Could anyone offer any advice or an opinion on this?

Comment: maybe stick-on anchors would work ...https://duckduckgo.com/?q=adhesive+cable+tie+base+anchor&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a blind pem nut? It might be hairy trying to make the a blind slot for the PEM nut, but even if you make a through-slot for it, it's a the blind PEM nut and if fitted well enough seals everything off anyways. You will need an arbor press and appropriate broach however, and likely a backing block for when you broach since the aluminum is thin.

Comment: This seems like an interesting idea as it doesn't required any welding. I'm considering buying these clinch nuts to try it out: [link](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/clinch-nuts/0827619). My approach would be to create the hole for the nut by milling to a depth of 2mm in the 3mm thick aluminium sheet. I'm a bit unsure whether the specs of the clinch nuts would suit what I'm trying to do though. What do you think?

Comment: That works too. You need no broach but still need an arbor press and backing support block. Is a mill accurate enough? You might need to ream and I think you could ream through if you find you can't shallow mill it since it should be a press fit anyways to seal things. What are you sealing out?

Comment: PEM nut is a genericized trademark for clinch nut I think, They come in shapes other than just round like hex but you need broaches for that.

Comment: I would test that you can't flex the sheet metal and have it pop out though. The flex might preclude through-hole due to the seal.

Comment: There's also rotary friction welding but that is exotic and will take lots of experimentation

Comment: For the arbor press, are you thinking something like [this](https://www.machinemart.co.uk/p/clarke-csa10ep-10-tonne-economy-hydraulic-floo/) would do the job?

Comment: You'd need to look up how much pressure is required for clinch nuts. You might be able to get away with a small 1, 2, or 5 tonne press table top one. I only know about manual presses which are probably more useful for press fitting things since you have more control. https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/p/GGS4Z329?cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwma6TBhDIARIsAOKuANzw2Nuw8h52b4Pzwd2uG_Pb-u7DeAx-XN96Hu4bpHX6aBiiApLKPQAaAkFgEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3645!3!303439923827!!!g!659510430637!&gclid=Cj0KCQjwma6TBhDIARIsAOKuANzw2Nuw8h52b4Pzwd2uG_Pb-u7DeAx-XN96Hu4bpHX6aBiiApLKPQAaAkFgEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: All good advice.... mill accuracy or even just finding the required size (4.75mm it seems) sounds like a challenge. This could certainly be a problem. For sealing, I'm trying to keep dust and moisture out. However, I'm also keen to keep one side of the aluminium sheet completely plain and free of fixings for aesthetic reasons too.

Comment: You could bore it though 4.75mm might be too small for a boring head with an adjustable bar

Comment: I looked up what I have at work and we have a 3 ton manual arbour press. A lot lower than I thought because it's massive and free standing. Must be for the height of the jaws because broaches are long. So I can't imagine you needing more than 3 tons, likely less. https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/p/WWG40F020?cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwma6TBhDIARIsAOKuANweh16E6mEXAsg_-Xq2krq9dNq0_B7TJcfEqgzOlOu82TjG59xYSNQaAnm4EALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3645!3!303439923827!!!g!659510430637!&gclid=Cj0KCQjwma6TBhDIARIsAOKuANweh16E6mEXAsg_-Xq2krq9dNq0_B7TJcfEqgzOlOu82TjG59xYSNQaAnm4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Never used it for clinch nuts though but I wouldn't hesitate. Of course, I also have one sitting here so I don't lose anything by trying. The guy I worked with seemed to have no reservations when talking about using clinch nuts in the past though, but we did not go that route so it remains untested.

Comment: Do you think it might it be necessary to mill out a 4.75 mm diameter pocket to 2 mm depth instead of trying to find a cutting tool that is 4.75 mm diameter?

Comment: Make it undersized however you want and follow with a 0.187" reamer = 4.7498mm. Make sure the reamer is "flat bottom" enough though since the end is chamfered for hole entry unless you can grind away the end to reduce the chamfered length. McMaster-Carr carries 0.187" reamers as well as 0.1865", etc.

Comment: Ok excellent.... looks like this would do the job: [link](https://www.protool-ltd.co.uk/p/a04750sar)

Comment: Oh yeah, that looks good.  Don't dwell too long. I'm told the exact size of the hole depends on how long you keep the reamer in and finicky things like coolant or no coolant.

Comment: Ok perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually holes are tapped to a depth of 1.5 times the diameter, and more for softer metals.

As aluminium is soft, then the thread will be engaging just one turn which won’t take much load at all.

A possibility is to weld a nut to the face side to give more purchase for the bolt and still leave the blind hole for the seal.

Comment: akin to that suggestion is to use a stud/spot welder similar to that used by Colin Furze
https://youtu.be/fqTDfpIpub4?t=521

Answer (score 1):

A [1.8mm flat bottom drill bit](https://www.travers.com/product/nachi-0715228-flat-bottom-high-performance-drill-20-149-108) and a [2mm bottoming tap](https://www.travers.com/product/nachi-91002-thread-forming-tap-12-488-440) will do what you need. You will need to use a drill bit collar or a depth limiter on your drill to prevent going all the way through. You will want to test the process on an non-critical piece of aluminum first. It would also be a good idea to test if the strength of the connection is going to be acceptable in your application.

In addition to the stud welder, welded nut, and expansion shield ideas; you could [braze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazing) on a nut or stud. Brazing aluminum is easier than welding it and you can use a metal other than aluminum for the nut or stud. You will need [Aluminum brazing rods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00012Y0FS) and a [MAPP gas torch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bernzomatic-Trigger-Start-Torch-Kit-TS4000KC/203368730). Again practice on a scrap piece of aluminum first.

Comment: @SolarMike Spelling corrected. Thanks

Comment: Often find it is the auto-typing or auto-correction that gets me...